# Material-ui radio button not working together with react-final-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-final-form

My material-ui radio button was originally working but when I implemented with react-final-form I can make to work. The thing now is that radio button not clickable at all, but when I remove the `...input` inside `inputProps` radio button works.

I know there's a material-ul react-final-form wrapper https://github.com/Deadly0/final-form-material-ui but I don't want to use it at the moment.

Any help there?

```
import { Box, Typography } from '@material-ui/core'
import { useCallback, useState } from 'react'
import { useContext } from '/form-context'
import { Field } from 'react-final-form'

const GetFruitFav = () => {
  const { values, setValues } = useContext()
  const { favFruits = 'orange' } = values || {}
  const [food, setFood] = useState(favFruits)

  const handleBtn = useCallback(
    (value) => {
      setFood(value)
    },
    [setFood]
  )

  return (
    <div>
          <Field
            name="food"
            type="radio"
            render={({ input, meta }) => (
              <StyledRadioBox>
                <StyledRadioButton
                  checked={food === 'orange'}
                  onChange={() => handleBtn('orange')}
                  value="orange"
                  name="orange"
                  inputProps={{
                    'aria-label': 'orange',
                    ...input,
                  }}
                />
              </StyledRadioBox>
            )}
          />
       
          <Field
            name="food"
            type="radio"
            render={({ input, meta }) => (
              <>
                <StyledRadioBox>
                  <StyledRadioButton
                    checked={food === 'grapes'}
                    onChange={() => handleBtn('grapes')}
                    value="grapes"
                    name="grapes"
                    inputProps={{
                      'aria-label': 'grapes',
                      ...input,
                    }}
                  />
                </StyledRadioBox>
              </>
            )}
          />
       </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically, what I wanted are when user clicked on material-ui radio button this will save to my react context at the same time react-final-form will save the values too.

I solved this problem, by refactoring my code

```
<Field
name = "food"
value = "orange"
type = "radio"
render = { ({ input: { checked, onChange, value, ..rest}, meta }) => ( 
     <StyledRadioBox >
        <StyledRadioButton checked = {checked}
        // let react-final-form handle this not material-ui
        onChange = {
            (event) => {
                onChange(event)
                handleBtn(value) 
           // uncontrolled let react-final-form handle the values instead of adding manually

            }
        }
        inputProps = {
            {
                'aria-label': 'orange',
                 value,
                ...rest,
                  
            }
        }
        /> 
    </StyledRadioBox>
    )
}
/>
```